# How to query between two dates using Laravel and Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, orm

I'm trying to create a report page that shows reports from a specific date to a specific date. Here's my current code:

```
$now = date('Y-m-d');
$reservations = Reservation::where('reservation_from', $now)->get();
```

What this does in plain SQL is `select * from table where reservation_from = $now`.

I have this query here but I don't know how to convert it to eloquent query.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE reservation_from BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to
```

How can I convert the code above to eloquent query?

Comment: what is the date format in `reservation_from`. you can use the Carbon values based on that.

Comment: date format is TIMESTAMP @AthiKrishnan

Comment: it would be like, `Reservation::where('reservation_from', '>=', Carbon::createFromDate(1975, 5, 21);)
->where('reservation_from', '<=', Carbon::createFromDate(2015, 5, 21);)->get()`;

Answer (score 468, accepted):

**The `whereBetween` method verifies that a column's value is between
two values.**

```
$from = date('2018-01-01');
$to = date('2018-05-02');

Reservation::whereBetween('reservation_from', [$from, $to])->get();
```

---

In some cases you need to add date range dynamically. Based on [@Anovative](https://stackoverflow.com/users/673846/anovative)'s comment you can do this:

```
Reservation::all()->filter(function($item) {
  if (Carbon::now()->between($item->from, $item->to)) {
    return $item;
  }
});
```

---

If you would like to add more condition then you can use `orWhereBetween`. If you would like to exclude a date interval then you can use `whereNotBetween` .

```
Reservation::whereBetween('reservation_from', [$from1, $to1])
  ->orWhereBetween('reservation_to', [$from2, $to2])
  ->whereNotBetween('reservation_to', [$from3, $to3])
  ->get();
```

---

Other useful where clauses: `whereIn`, `whereNotIn`, `whereNull`, `whereNotNull`, `whereDate`, `whereMonth`, `whereDay`, `whereYear`, `whereTime`, `whereColumn` , `whereExists`, `whereRaw`.

[Laravel docs about Where Clauses.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: How would this be handled if the `$from` and `$to` would be dynamic dates that belong to the model?  As in there is an `effective_at` and `expires_at` fields and I want to query to see if the current item is within that range. I tried `each()` with an if that uses `Carbon::now()->between( ... )`, however it still returns all results.

Comment: EDIT for my above comment:
Overlooked `filter()`, that did the trick.

    `MyModel::all()->where('column', 'value')->filter(function ($item) {
        if (Carbon::now->between($item->effective_at, $item->expires_at)) {
            return $item;
        }
    })->first();`

Comment: @Anovative thanks for your useful comment. I'll update my answer based on your comment.

Comment: it will only give from date record.

Comment: @Muhammad it should work with primitive values. `OrderItem::whereBetween('count', [5, 10])->get()`

Comment: There is a problem with the second method. It will load all records from DB to memory and then only it will perform the filtering.

Comment: Looking for WhereDateIn - Array haha.

Comment: Thank you this is the simplies solution in my case

Answer (score 28):

And I have created the model scope

To Know More about `scopes` check out the below links:

- [laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes)
- [medium.com/@janaksan/using-scope-with-laravel](https://medium.com/@janaksan_/using-scope-with-laravel-7c80dd6a2c3d)

Code:

```
   /**
     * Scope a query to only include the last n days records
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeWhereDateBetween($query,$fieldName,$fromDate,$todate)
    {
        return $query->whereDate($fieldName,'>=',$fromDate)->whereDate($fieldName,'<=',$todate);
    }
```

And in the controller, add the Carbon Library to top

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

To get the **last 10 days** record from now

```
 $lastTenDaysRecord = ModelName::whereDateBetween('created_at',(new Carbon)->subDays(10)->startOfDay()->toDateString(),(new Carbon)->now()->endOfDay()->toDateString() )->get();
```

To get the **last 30 days** record from now

```
 $lastThirtyDaysRecord = ModelName::whereDateBetween('created_at',(new Carbon)->subDays(30)->startOfDay()->toDateString(),(new Carbon)->now()->endOfDay()->toDateString() )->get();
```

Comment: WhereDateBetween second param needs to be an array.

Comment: It's just a scope of the model it's not Builder method

Comment: Oh yeah, missed that somehow. My bad:)

Answer (score 26):

Another option if your field is `datetime` instead of `date` (*although it works for both cases*):

```
$fromDate = "2016-10-01";
$toDate = "2016-10-31";

$reservations = Reservation::whereRaw(
  "(reservation_from >= ? AND reservation_from <= ?)", 
  [
     $fromDate ." 00:00:00", 
     $toDate ." 23:59:59"
  ]
)->get();
```

Comment: technically wouldn't it need to be $toDate . " 23:59.59.999" ?

Comment: @stevepowell2000 It depends on your database, in my case we store the date  with this format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' in a datetime mysql field, without microseconds precision. Related info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: Great point. So if it was a datetime or timestamp field we *may* to go all the way out to 23:59:59.999999

"A DATETIME or TIMESTAMP value can include a trailing fractional seconds part in up to microseconds (6 digits) precision."

Comment: thank you you've been help me to do my task before! love this answer bro! :)
-habie

Answer (score 23):

If you want to check if current date exist in between two dates in db:
=>here the query will get the application list if employe's application from and to date is exist in todays date.

```
$list=  (new LeaveApplication())
            ->whereDate('from','<=', $today)
            ->whereDate('to','>=', $today)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 18):

The following should work:

```
$now = date('Y-m-d');
$reservations = Reservation::where('reservation_from', '>=', $now)
                           ->where('reservation_from', '<=', $to)
                           ->get();
```

Answer (score 13):

If you need to have in when a datetime field should be like this.

```
return $this->getModel()->whereBetween('created_at', [$dateStart." 00:00:00",$dateEnd." 23:59:59"])->get();
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a question that already has many answers, please be sure to add some additional insight into why the response you're providing is substantive and not simply echoing what's already been vetted by the original poster. This is especially important in "code-only" answers such as the one you've provided.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

Since you are fetching based on a single column value you can simplify your query likewise:

```
$reservations = Reservation::whereBetween('reservation_from', array($from, $to))->get();
```

Retrieve based on condition: [laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects)

Hope this helped.

Comment: Be careful if you want a register from 1 of feb 2021 to 31 may 2021 and this register was created at 31 may 2021 it will not work, in that case you should use this: `whereDate('created_at', '>=', $this->start_date)
                                ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $this->end_date)
                                ->get()`

Answer (score 6):

I followed the valuable solutions provided by other contributors and faced a  minor issue no one has addressed. If the `reservation_from` is a datetime column then it might not produce results as expected and will miss all the records in which the date is same but time is anything above 00:00:00 time. To improve the above code a bit a small tweak is needed like so.

```
$from = Carbon::parse();
$to = Carbon::parse();
$from = Carbon::parse('2018-01-01')->toDateTimeString();
//Include all the results that fall in $to date as well
$to = Carbon::parse('2018-05-02')
    ->addHours(23)
    ->addMinutes(59)
    ->addSeconds(59)
    ->toDateTimeString();
//Or $to can also be like so
$to = Carbon::parse('2018-05-02')
    ->addHours(24)
    ->toDateTimeString();
Reservation::whereBetween('reservation_from', [$from, $to])->get();
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this might be an old question but I just found myself in a situation where I had to implement this feature in a Laravel 5.7 app. Below is what worked from me.

```
 $articles = Articles::where("created_at",">", Carbon::now()->subMonths(3))->get();
```

You will also need to use Carbon

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me add proper syntax with the exact timestamp

Before

```
$from = $request->from;
$to = $request->to;
Reservation::whereBetween('reservation_from', [$from, $to])->get();
```

After

```
$from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->from));
$to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->to));
Reservation::whereBetween('reservation_from', [$from, $to])->get();
```

Note: if you stored date in string form, then make sure to pass the exact format in from and to. Which will be matched with DB.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my answer is working thank  you Artisan Bay i read your comment to use wheredate()

It Worked

```
public function filterwallet($id,$start_date,$end_date){

$fetch = DB::table('tbl_wallet_transactions')
->whereDate('date_transaction', '>=', $start_date)                                 
->whereDate('date_transaction', '<=', $end_date)                                 
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

the trick is to change it :

```
Reservation::whereBetween('reservation_from', [$from, $to])->get();
```

to

```
Reservation::whereBetween('reservation_from', ["$from", "$to"])->get();
```

because the date must be in string type in mysql

Answer (score 1):

@masoud , in Laravel, you have to request the field value from form.So,

```
    Reservation::whereBetween('reservation_from',[$request->from,$request->to])->get();
```

And in livewire, a slight change-

```
    Reservation::whereBetween('reservation_from',[$this->from,$this->to])->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `DB::raw('')` to make the column as date MySQL with using whereBetween function as :

```
    Reservation::whereBetween(DB::raw('DATE(`reservation_from`)'),
    [$request->from,$request->to])->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$trans_from = date('2022-10-08');
$trans_to = date('2022-10-12');
$filter_transactions =  DB::table('table_name_here')->whereBetween('created_at', [$trans_from, $trans_to])->get();
```