# Laravel 5.5 where condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have problem in searching, I am using Laravel 5.5 version, the situation like this: I have groups which study during some period of time. On filtering page, Admin enters study starting date and ending date, the result must show all groups which studied or studying between given time period. A comparing in simple way is not working, I would like to use `strtotime` function, but when I use:

```php
->where(strtotime('edu_ending_date'),'=<',strtotime($edu_ending_date));
```

the eloquent is saying there is not such a column name ...

```php
if(!empty($input['daterange']))
{
     $q->where(function($query)use($edu_starting_date,$edu_ending_date){
           $query->where('edu_starting_date', '>=', "$edu_starting_date")
           ->where('edu_ending_date','=<',"$edu_ending_date");
     });
}
```

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361628/laravel-eloquent-date-range-query-between-two-dates

Comment: What type of column is `edu_starting_date`? What format is the value of `$edu_starting_date`?

Answer (score 1):

if you need to use dates in your where clauses I might want to have a look at [this article](http://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-date-filtering-wheredate-and-other-methods/) and [this section of laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses) where they mention additional where clauses which include also `whereDate`, `whereDay`, etc. Might come in handy. In your case I would suggest you to do two `whereDate` conditions to act as between:

```
$query->whereDate('edu_starting_date', '>=', $edu_starting_date)
      ->whereDate('edu_ending_date', '=<', $edu_ending_date)
```

Note that `$edu_starting_date` and `$edu_ending_date` are recommended to be a `Carbon` object or output of PHP's `date` function. If you want to use strings according to the Laravel docs it should be possible. Hopefully this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$q->whereBetween('edu_starting_date', [$edu_starting_date,$edu_ending_date])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    if(!empty($input['daterange']))
    {
        $q->where(function($query)use($edu_starting_date,$edu_ending_date){
            $query->where('edu_starting_date', '>=', $edu_starting_date)
                ->where('edu_ending_date','=<',$edu_ending_date);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The date is saved as a string in my database, is that ok, that is why I would like to use 
something like this:

```
->where(strtotime('edu_ending_date'),'=<',strtotime($edu_ending_date));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DB::raw

```
->where(DB::raw("strtotime('edu_ending_date')"),'=<',strtotime($edu_ending_date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, I found my stupid mistake, I stored date as a string.