# MySQL date in between month and year

Tags: mysql, laravel

How to query date month and year between `from_date` and `to_date`?

What I tired:

```
$posts = my_table::whereYear('from_date', '>=', $year)
    ->whereMonth('from_date', '>=', $month)
    ->whereYear('to_date', '<=', $year)
    ->whereMonth('to_date', '<=', $month)
    ->get();
```

Query I want to execute:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE (MONTH(from_date)>=2 AND (Year(from_date)>=2019)
  AND (MONTH(to_date)=<4 AND (Year(to_date)=<2019)
```

Comment: Can you share what output you are getting from this query, And what will be the output you expected.

Comment: There's not built-in `DAYOFMONTH` "macro" so you would need to do `whereRaw("DAYOFMONTH(date) > ?", [11])` etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query between two dates using Laravel and Eloquent ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361628/how-to-query-between-two-dates-using-laravel-and-eloquent-orm)

Comment: It is not duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you might be looking for:

```
$posts = my_table::whereRaw("(MONTH('from_date') > 2 AND YEAR('from_date') >= 2019)")
    ->whereRaw("(MONTH('to_date') < 4 AND YEAR('to_date') <= 2019)")
    ->get();
```

Here's an [example](https://implode.io/Lyzbj9).

Comment: Thanks. It is very useful

Comment: Did it work for you? If yes, please consider accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the eloquent method too.

```
$result = my_table::where(function($query){
       $query->where(DB::raw('MONTH(from_date)'), '>=' , 2)
        ->where(DB::raw('Year(from_date)'), '>=' , 2019);
      })
     ->where(function($query){
       $query->where(DB::raw('MONTH(to_date)'), '<=' , 4)
        ->where(DB::raw('YEAR(to_date)'), '<=' , 2019);
      })
     ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

you may also do it in this way.

```
return Post::whereRaw("STR_TO_DATE('from_date', '%M%Y') > STR_TO_DATE('022019', '%M%Y')")
->whereRaw("STR_TO_DATE('from_date', '%M%Y') < STR_TO_DATE('042019', '%M%Y')")
->get();
```