# How can i show single data in view if today date is in between start date & end date in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have Admission table which have id, school_id, start_date,end_date etc and i want to show single data if today's date is between start_date & end_Date in laravel eloquent

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: i didnot tried yet, can you help

Comment: it's not a writing code service, if you want some help, you need to try something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query between two dates using Laravel and Eloquent ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361628/how-to-query-between-two-dates-using-laravel-and-eloquent-orm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying below code you can get the latest data of current date

```
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d');

$result = my_table::where(DB::raw('DATE(start_date)'), '<=' , $currentDate)
       ->where(DB::raw('DATE(end_Date)'), '>' , $currentDate)
       ->orderBy('id','desc')
       ->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`$start_date = date('2018-01-01');
$end_date = date('2018-05-02');

Adminssion::whereBetween(Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateString(), [$start_date, $end_date])->get();`
```

The **carbon now()** function will give you current date and time. And **toDateString()** function only give you today date. And with **whereBetween()** function you can compare the current date between start_date and end_date.