# How to retrieve data of current date in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I want to retrieve data of today from my database in Laravel.

I have already googling and applied several methods but not getting my answer.

```
PrescriptionTbl::whereDate('created_at', '=', $today)->get();
```

Where `PrescriptionTbl` is the model and `today` is current date like `2019-2-19`.But got NULL array.

To check the SQL I have used `toSQL()` instead of `get()`...and it shows below SQL in the browser

```
 select * from `prescription_tbls` where date(`created_at`) = ?
```

I have also use `Carbon` but also get a NULL array

```
PrescriptionTbl::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->get();
```

How to solve it? Anybody Help Please?

Comment: Did you try ``PrescriptionTbl::where('created_at', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))->get();`` ?

Comment: FGDeveloper...Actually I want to retrieve data Date wise....That's why didn't use `H:i:s`

Comment: You can use that; ``PrescriptionTbl::whereDate('created_at', date('Y-m-d'))->get();`` It works for me.

Comment: Can you please share the date format used by the fileld so that i can modify my function and post the answer and dont' forget to add some example dates

Comment: FGDeveloper....it works according to your code...Please provide the answer and I will accept your answer then

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use that;

```
PrescriptionTbl::whereDate('created_at', date('Y-m-d'))->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get it via `new DateTime()` class

```
PrescriptionTbl::whereDate('created_at', '=', (new DateTime)->format('Y-m-d'))->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using  **Carbon** ( use Carbon\Carbon; ) its simple and pretty

```
PrescriptionTbl::whereDate('created_at',  Carbon::today()->toDateString())->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this one:**

```
PrescriptionTbl::where('created_at', '<=', date('Y-m-d 00:00:00'))->get();
```

Comment: Sahil Darji.... I want to retrieve data as Date wise.....And in my database `created_at` column format is `DATETIME`

Answer (score 0):

created_at is a timestamp which is date/time format, so, equal operator wouldn't work unless you provided the whole timestamp.

you can use whereDate method to compare dates only as mentioned in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses)

```
PrescriptionTbl::whereDate('created_at', $today)->get();
```

Comment: it shows `select * from `prescription_tbls` where `created_at` > ? and `created_at` = ?` after using `toSql()` and also get NULL result

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereBetween` in which you can provide start date of today as `2019-01-01 00:00:00` and end date as `2019-01-01 23:59:59`

For reference 
[How to query between two dates using Laravel and Eloquent ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361628/how-to-query-between-two-dates-using-laravel-and-eloquent-orm)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the exact record of today's transactions is by using the `like` operator in conjunction with Carbon for example in Laravel 9+:

```php
<?php

$date = Carbon::now();

    $todaySales = Sales::query()
        ->where("created_at", "like", "%{$date->today()->toDateString()}%")
        ->get();

    dd($todaySales);
```

The above will return an array of records for today.

Now why do we use this approach? I want you to take a good look at the created_at column field this is how it looks like: `2023-04-14 11:33:23`. With this using where statement the result will be an empty array why? Because where statement uses an `=` operator by default which means the sql statement will attempt to match the records exactly the way it is. Here is how the query will look like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM sales WHERE created_at={$todaysDate}
// in this case todays date is 2023-04-14 
// but the value in the database is rather containing time 
// e.g.: 023-04-14 11:33:23 so definitely the select operation will fail and return empty results.
```

Looking at the above query there's no way the sql query is going to evaluate to any result but with the `like` operator the sql query will attempt to search for records that has todays date in them: `2023-04-14` which will return all records for today. If you're looking to retrieve records from a range let's say from Monday through to Friday you can use Laravel `whereBetween()` method otherwise try this approach. Hope this help you solve the problem.

You can also checkout [this article](https://obitechinvents.blogspot.com/2023/04/how-to-retrieve-data-of-current-date-in.html) for more info