# Laravel Datepicker Failed to parse time string

Tags: laravel, date, parsing, datepicker, php-carbon

I'm trying to build a query in Laravel using whereBetween and I have a problem with the dates-range. I'm using Carbon to get the inputs, looking like this:

```
$dateRange = Carbon::parse($request->get('anniversary'));
```

I received the following error on submit:

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (06/01/2019 - 06/30/2019) at position 11 (-): Unexpected character
```

Then, I changed the $dateRange in this form:

```
$dateRange = Carbon::parse(str_replace('-', '', $request->get('anniversary')));
```

After that, this error occured:

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (06/01/2019 06/30/2019) at position 12 (0): Double date specification
```

The whereBetween clause looks like this:

```
->whereBetween('anniversary', [$dateRange])
```

Any ideas on how can I fix this?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361628/how-to-query-between-two-dates-using-laravel-and-eloquent-orm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361628/how-to-query-between-two-dates-using-laravel-and-eloquent-orm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explode the retrieved Datepicker to two values. (Start Date and End Date)

```
$dateArray = explode('-', $request->get('anniversary'));

$startDate = $dateArray[0];
$endDate = $dateArray[1];
```

Now you can use

```
->whereBetween('anniversary', $dateArray);
```