# Get database search results between two date time period

Tags: mysql, laravel, datetime, date-range, laravel-query-builder

In my database, there is a table called vehicle_schedule, and all the vehicle schedules are stored there. In that table, there is two columns name as `date_from` `date_to`.Both columns type is `datetime`.When I pass date like `2019-03-20 09:00:00` `2019-03-25 12:00:00` I need to get all the vehicle schedules between that two DateTime range.

So far I have tried this,

```
$vehicleSchedule=DB::table('vehicle_schedule')
->select('vehicle_schedule.*')
->whereRaw("date_from >=? AND date_to <=?",array($date_from,$date_to))
->get();
return response()->json(["vehicleSchedule"=>$vehicleSchedule,"message"=>"Vehicle Schedule got successfully"]);
```

I expect all the vehicle schedules are in that given range. But it only got vehicle schedules between date values only. When I check with the time constraint it does not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend to use `PHP Carbon` to work with any `datetime` or `timestamp` field.

To convert the datetime field to Carbon use this in model.

```
protected $dates = ['date_from','date_to'];
```

Then, convert the input time to Carbon inside controller

```
$date_from = Carbon::parse('2019-03-20 09:00:00');
$date_to = Carbon::parse('2019-03-25 12:00:00');
```

In this way the query will more shorter, cleaner and efficient.

```
$vehicleSchedule = DB::table('vehicle_schedule')
    ->where('date_from','>=',$date_from)
    ->where('date_to','<=',$date_to)
    ->get();
```

Comment: You have replaced one syntax with another without solving the problem.

Comment: @SalmanA the date should be greater than `2019-03-20 09:00:00` and smaller then `2019-03-25 12:00:00`. I don't see any problem with the syntax.

Comment: ***If I understand the problem correctly*** then OP is already getting this result (_but it only got vehicle schedules between date values only_). This query will not match a vehicle scheduled for 2019-03-22 ... 2019-03-28 if the user searched for 2019-03-20 ... 2019-03-25. But that is my understanding of the question, not necessarily correct.

Comment: @SalmanA I think his result is working with date only. He want it to work with both date & time.

Comment: @smartrahat this worked for me. This trick really recommends for use with DateTime.Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Laravel `whereBetween` for this:

```
$vehicleSchedule=DB::table('vehicle_schedule')
    ->select('vehicle_schedule.*')
    ->whereBetween('date_from', [$startDate, $endDate])
    ->whereBetween('date_to', [$startDate, $endDate])
    ->get();
```

This will only select records where the `date_from` and `date_to` are between the two dates.

[Related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361628/how-to-query-between-two-dates-using-laravel-and-eloquent).
[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses).

Comment: I would also suggest converting your dates (`$endDate` and `$startDate`) into Carbon, as smartrahat has suggested.

Comment: This is probably the easiest solution.

Comment: What if $start and $end dates are 2019-10-10 and 2019-10-20 and from and to dates are 2019-10-01 and 2019-10-31?

Comment: @SalmanA it really depends on the structure of the data being held in the database. I totally see your point, but it depends how these schedules are being stored - is there a record per day/per hour? In this case, that would catch that fine. If they are being stored in large chunks like you've suggested, then it won't get caught.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('2019-03-20 09:00:00'));
$end_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('2019-03-25 12:00:00'));

$vehicleSchedule=DB::table('vehicle_schedule')
->select('vehicle_schedule.*')
->where([['date_from','<=',$start_date],['date_to','>=',$end_date]])->orwhereBetween('date_from',array($start_date,$end_date))->orWhereBetween('date_to',array($start_date,$end_date))
->get();
```