# Multiple Where condition in laravel 5.8 not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I am trying to fetch data by using item name, date from, date to

if im using

```
$data=add_items::select('*')->where('item_name',$request->iname)->orWhere('date',$request->datef)->orWhere('date',$request->datet)->get();
```

it showing the result but it according to item name, not showing the result within the specific date

e.g

```
[
    {"id":2,item_name":"Muesli","date":"2019-12-23"}, 
    {"id":3,"item_name":"Muesli","date":"2020-12-24"}
]
```

if i'm using simple where with all these three conditions it returns no result

```
 $data=add_items::select('*')->where('item_name',$request->iname)->where('date',$request->datef)->where('date',$request->datet)->get();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query between two dates using Laravel and Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361628/how-to-query-between-two-dates-using-laravel-and-eloquent)

Comment: no this is not.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
$data=add_items::select('*')->where(function($q) use ($request) {
   $q->where('item_name',$request->iname)
     ->orWhere('date',$request->datef)
     ->orWhere('date',$request->datet);
})->get();
```

Read about [parameter grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#parameter-grouping) for details.

Comment: "Undefined variable: q"

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to filter item name, `date from`, `date to`

I think you can use whereBetween to filter the date:

```php
$data=add_items::where('item_name', $request->iname)
               ->orWhereBetween('date',[$request->datef, $request->datet]);
               ->get();
```

Comment: @guzu do u means you want the `item_name` and the date between `datef` and `datet`, or u want `item_name` or the date between `datef` and `datet`?

Comment: second one option