# How to get customer between two dates in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, date

My Date format is 26-June-2020 and i run sql query

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE date BETWEEN '26-June-2020' AND '30-June-2020'
```

but its not working good its getting record from 26-june-2020 to 3-July-2020

and my laravel code is this:

```
$customers = Customer::whereBetween('date', array($datefrom, $dateto))->get();
```

Comment: Its Should be **'26-06-2020' AND '30-06-2020'**, not `'26-June-2020' AND '30-June-2020'`

Comment: I have too much data in my table with this format 26-june-2020. is there any way to solve using this?

Answer (score 4):

You first need to convert the dates to [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) objects

```
$from = Carbon::parse($dateFrom)
    ->startOfDay()
    ->toDateTimeString();

$to = Carbon::parse($dateTo)
    ->endOfDay()
    ->toDateTimeString();

$customers = Customer::whereBetween('date', [$from, $to])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is date format of $datefrom $dateto, I found a issue like your question
[How to query between two dates using Laravel and Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361628/how-to-query-between-two-dates-using-laravel-and-eloquent).
Hoping it help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question, [vote to close](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). If not, *tailor the answer to this specific question*.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in the format (e.g.) `01-June-2020` that means that your data is not correctly formatted as dates. This means you need to convert them to dates before getting a correct `BETWEEN` result. Not doing so will yield you a `BETWEEN` result comparing dates as strings, which will mean `01-June-2020` will come before `02-January-2020`.

```
$customers = Customer::whereBetween(
    DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d-%M-%Y')"), 
    array($datefrom, $dateto) // These should also be correctly formatted as YYYY-MM-DD or as carbon objects
)->get();
```

However the major drawback of this approach is that you cannot use any indexes making any queries much slower than they could be if you permanently covert the given column to date objects and add an index.

This solution utilises [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)