# How To Add Interval 30 Days in Laravel (MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hi I got stack when i want to show data using interval in Laravel, I have this code and it's running well on Mysql and showing what i want. but how to implement the mysql code to laravel ?

this is mySql code

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE end_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

and i have trying some ways on Laravel Controller but array is null

```
$highlightProject = project::select('*')->where(DB::raw('end_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)'))->get();
    dd($highlightProject);
```

Comment: Can you verify that query generated correctly by checking a log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you're not getting the results you want is because you're using `where` instead of `whereRaw`. In this case your query going to return:

```
select * from `projects` 
where end_date BETWEEN 
    CURRENT_DATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) is null
```

(notice the `is null` part).

To get the results you want change `where` to `whereRaw` (you can remove the `DB::raw`):

```
project::whereRaw('end_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)')->get();
```

---

Alternatively, you could use a mixture of [whereBetween](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses) and [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub):

```
project::whereBetween('end_date', [now(), now()->addDays(30)])->get();
```

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361628/how-to-query-between-two-dates-using-laravel-and-eloquent) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the solution you would have preferred, (I do not know why your current query would not work and as @tadman suggested, I too suggest checking the produced query), but an alternative approach would be to try with query builder methods and Carbon date library that is shipped with Laravel.

```
$highlightProject = Project::whereBetween('end_date', [\Carbon\Carbon::today(), \Carbon\Carbon::today()->addDays(30)])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try with whereRaw() sometime where() not properly work DB::raw()**

```
$highlightProject = project::select('*')->whereRaw(DB::raw('end_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)'))->get();
```

Comment: You don't need to use `DB::raw` with `whereRaw` :)