# making report in laravel By Custom Date

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My Code here is returning products in every month how can i change it so i return products in custom date like

from 20/8/2020 to 25/8/2020

```
$products= \App\OrderProduct::select(
                DB::raw('MONTHNAME(created_at) as month'),
                DB::raw('sum(line_total) as total_line') , 'product_id','qty','line_total','created_at')->groupBy('month','product_id')->get();
```

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361628/how-to-query-between-two-dates-using-laravel-and-eloquent

Answer (score 0):

you can use `whereBetween` clause for that and you can pass `$from` and `to` date to it. see [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses) for it