# how to pass the query result to the view? Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I can not get the result of such a request:

```
$performance = DB::select("SELECT ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(NOW(), date_finish))/60) FROM tickets WHERE id = ?", [$id]);
```

the result comes in the form of an array:

```
array:1 [
 0 => {#1385 
  +"ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(NOW(), date_finish))/60)": "299"
 }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Thats becouse your not included `get()` in end of your code.
Replace this:

```
$performance = DB::select("SELECT ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(NOW(), date_finish))/60) FROM tickets WHERE id = ?", [$id])->get();
```

with this:

```
$performance = DB::select("SELECT ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(NOW(), date_finish))/60) FROM tickets WHERE id = ?", [$id]);
```

Comment: now wrote the request correctly 
$performance = DB::table('tickets')->selectRaw('ROUND(TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(NOW(), date_finish))/60)')->where('id', $id)->get();
but still the result is output as an array

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="performance" value="{{ $performance }}">

Comment: May I ask what your query does?

Comment: this query gets the difference between the dates of the given string

Comment: Did you tried `whereBetween`?  Look at this link too https://stackoverflow.com/a/33361741/13661216