# Custom validation rule , check if date range is already taken or not

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have to manage the reservation for the rental of a house, when I make a new reservation the start date and the end date should be free.

For example, if I make a reservation for a client from September 23 to September 28, I cannot create another reservation over this date.
I would need an eloquent query that could check that started_at and ends_at (of the form) are not included between the already existing dates

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query between two dates using Laravel and Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361628/how-to-query-between-two-dates-using-laravel-and-eloquent)

Comment: I tried several queries but for example if I take from December 5th to December 8th and then I make a new reservation from December 3rd to December 10th it doesn't put an error. But from December 6 to December 7 it puts an error.

I don't see how to make this request

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution :

```
$bookings = DB::table('bookings')
    ->where(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
        $q->where('started_at', '>=', $start)
            ->where('started_at', '<=', $end);
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
        $q->where('ends_at', '>=', $start)
            ->where('ends_at', '<=', $end);
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
        $q->where('started_at', '<', $start)
            ->where('ends_at', '>', $end);
    })
    ->count();
```