# I want to retrieve with an element that is between two given dates according to the current date

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to do a query to retrieve publications that are between two dates that are given in my db,

I think there is an error in my query because I am not recovering anything at all, do you see anything wrong?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\OfficialMessage;


class MessageController extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
        $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $official_message = OfficialMessage::all()
        ->where($today, '>=', 'publication_start_at', '&&', $today, '<=', 'publication_end_at')
        ->sortBy('publication_start_at');

        return view('front.pages.message', [
            'messages' => $official_message,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try `whereBetween`, like shown in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361628/how-to-query-between-two-dates-using-laravel-and-eloquent)

Comment: Do you get a result if you remove the WHERE clause completely? If you try you will know for sure that it is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Instead of using an php date in a php variable, consider using the mysql ``NOW()`` function.

Comment: Thanks you, i modified and is good. I changed the syntax and put now like this :         ```$official_message = OfficialMessage::all()
        ->where('publication_start_at', '<=', Now())
        ->where('publication_end_at', '>=', Now())
        ->sortBy('publication_start_at');```

Comment: @tola Can't use BETWEEN here because fields are different.

Answer (score 0):

Replace you WHERE like this:

```
->where('NOW() >= publication_start_at AND NOW() <= publication_end_at')
```