# how can i fetch records between two specific hours in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, php-8.1

I have two working shift first from 8:00 Am to 17:00:00PM second From 17:00:00PM to 8:00AM next day, How can I fetch records between two hours by carbon
`{{\App\Models\PolicyDetail::wheredate('second_scale', \Carbon\Carbon::today())->count()}}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query between two dates using Laravel and Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361628/how-to-query-between-two-dates-using-laravel-and-eloquent)

Answer (score 0):

$from = date('2018-01-01 05:00:00');
$to = date('2018-05-02 09:00:00');

User::whereBetween('applied_on', [$from, $to])->get();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).