# how to get data from 19:00:00 pm to 07:00:00 am

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
$star = $request->input('start_date'). ' ' . '19:00:00';
$end = $request->input('end_date'). ' ' . '07:00:00';
$employee_qty_in_shift2 = PatrolGateSurveillanceTransaction::where('type', 1)
        ->where('client_location_id', $request->client_location_id)
        ->where('created_at', '>=', $star)
        ->where('created_at', '<=', $end)
        ->sum('employee_qty'); dd($employee_qty_in_shift2);
```

The above code cannot filter data from **19:00:00 to 07:00:00**

Expected result:

```
created_at 
2022-10-12 19:00:00 
2022-10-13 20:00:00 
2022-10-12 21:00:00 
2022-10-12 22:00:00 
2022-10-12 23:00:00 
2022-10-12 23:59:59 
2022-10-13 01:00:00 
2022-10-13 02:00:00 
2022-10-13 03:00:00 
2022-10-13 04:00:00 
2022-10-13 05:00:00 
2022-10-13 06:00:00 
2022-10-13 07:00:00
```

Comment: Provide input examples and your expected outputs

Comment: Did you try [wherebetween](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)

Comment: Are your input dates correct...? Because normally there's no reason why it shouldn't work. To try otherwise as @RiggsFolly says with between. Example `where dateInBdd between '2022-10-12 19:00:00' and '2022-10-13 07:00:00'`

Comment: Sorry but if you write comments in anything but English most of us wont understand

Comment: Check this thread out [where between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361628/how-to-query-between-two-dates-using-laravel-and-eloquent)

Comment: between doesn't support for time

Comment: You are looking with date information for data in a field that only contains time..?????

Comment: I'm interested to see what is the value for `input('start_date')` and `input('end_date')`

Answer (score 0):

> The above code cannot filter data from 19:00:00 to 07:00:00

Of course. The is no value which is above `19:00:00` **and** below `07:00:00` **at the same time**.

Possible solution 1: Check that the time value is above `19:00:00` **OR** that it is below `07:00:00`. I.e. use `OrWhere`, not `Between` (mixing AND and OR - do not forget about operators precedence).

Possible solution 2: substract 19 hours from the value then check that the timepart of the result is between `00:00:00` and `12:00:00`.

In any case you must extract the timepart from complete datetime value - i.e. you must check not `created_at` but `TIME(created_at)`.

Comment: can i get an example?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use whereBetween, not two where clauses. Using where implies AND, not OR, and you can't have a condition where the value will be above 19:00:00 AND below 07:00:00 (for the same date, anyways).

```
$star = $request->input('start_date'). ' ' . '19:00:00';
$end = $request->input('end_date'). ' ' . '07:00:00';
$employee_qty_in_shift2 = PatrolGateSurveillanceTransaction::where('type', 1)
        ->whereBetween('created_at',[$star,$end])
        ->where('client_location_id', $request->client_location_id)
        ->sum('employee_qty');
```