# Get employees birthdays within next 3 days including today in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm truing to get the employees that have birthday within next 3 days. I tried to do that by using the following query.

```
public function upcomingBirthdays()
{
    $from = now()->format('m-d');
    $to = now()->addDays(3)->format('m-d');

    $employees = Employees::whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%m-%d') BETWEEN '{$from}' AND '{$to}'")
                          ->where('team_id', 13)
                          ->where('status', 1)
                          ->orderBy('dob', 'DESC')
                          ->get();

    return view('frontend.employee.birthdays', compact('employees'));
}
// End Method
```

But this is not returning expected data.

Today is **2022-11-09**

This is returning employees with birthdays **between** *2022-11-08* and *2022-11-10*. But **not returning** employees that have **birthdays on 11-11 and 11-12**.

Comment: This answer should provide some insight https://stackoverflow.com/a/33361741/2757519

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that finally worked for me:

```
$employees = Employees::where('team_id', 13)
                        ->where('status', 1)
                        ->where(function($q){
                            $q->where('dob', 'like', '%' . Carbon::now()->format('m-d'))
                            ->orWhere('dob', 'like', '%' . Carbon::now()->addDays()->format('m-d'))
                            ->orWhere('dob', 'like', '%' . Carbon::now()->addDays(2)->format('m-d'))
                            ->orWhere('dob', 'like', '%' . Carbon::now()->addDays(3)->format('m-d'))
                            ->orderBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(dob,'%m-%d')"), 'ASC');
                        })
                        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably related with the date formatting. Using DD instead of d you get a leading zero for single digit day of the month. Same for month: use MM instead of m.

Note: This will still fail for birthdays falling on January 1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a Carbon package from nesbot to handling date.
I haven't tested querying within date with built-in PHP but my code works with Carbon package.

So, on your case, try this:

```
$employees = Employee::whereBetween('dob', [Carbon::now(), Carbon::now()->addDay(3)])->get();
```