# search for records created from one date to another date

Tags: laravel

i need to search for records created from one date to another date.

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->whereDate('created_at', '2023-06-01')
                ->get();
```

The query that i make searches me only on a specific date, how can search between two dates?

**2023-06-01 at 2023-07-01**

Comment: Probably by using `whereBetween()` ? https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-eloquent-wherebetween-query-exampleexample.html or [laravel's docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query between two dates using Laravel and Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361628/how-to-query-between-two-dates-using-laravel-and-eloquent)

Comment: there is answer from WakilAhmed. That is the right one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `whereBetween` in the following way:

```
$startDate = '2023-06-01';
$endDate = '2023-07-01';

$users = DB::table('users')
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [$startDate, $endDate])
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `whereBetween()` in your query, it will give you data that exists between two dates, excluding the data on date B. However, if you want to include the data created on date B as well, you can use `whereRaw()` with the following SQL expression:

```php
whereRaw('DATE(column_name) BETWEEN DATE(?) AND DATE(?)', [$dateA, $dateB])
```

This way, you'll get all the data that falls within the range starting from date A up to and including date B. Remember to replace 'column_name' with the actual column you want to filter and `$dateA` and `$dateB` with the specific dates you are interested in.

Keep in mind that using `whereRaw()` allows you to directly write SQL expressions, so make sure to validate and sanitize the input to prevent any SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Raw query can lead to SQL Injection

Comment: @YusufGiovanno maybe [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#introduction) will convince you

Comment: Raw statements will be injected into the query as strings, so you should be extremely careful to avoid creating SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Using the laravel parameter binding, those variables are escaped and sanitized automatically, also the `DATE(?)` turn any string to date, if its not a valid date it will return null

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using "whereBetween" function

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$startDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2016-06-01')->startOfDay();
    
$endDate = $startDate->addMonth(1);
    
$users = DB::table('users')
         ->whereBetween('created_at', [$startDate, $endDate])
         ->get();
```