# Querying between two dates with Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a reservation table. When they search for a reservation here, I do not want any data to come up if it includes any of these dates. I have tried everything but have failed. What could be the problem?

```php
$startDate = Carbon::parse($request->start);
$startDate->addDay()->format('Y-m-d');
$endDate = Carbon::parse($request->end);
$endDate->addDay()->format('Y-m-d');

$suits = Homes::where('type', 0)
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->where('info_capacity', '<=', $countPeople)
            ->with('Reservations')
            ->whereHas('Reservations', function ($query) use ($endDate, $startDate) {
            $query->where('start_date', '=>', $startDate->format('Y-m-d'));
            $query->where('end_date', '<', $endDate->format('Y-m-d'));
        })
            ->get();

        return response()->json(HomesListResource::collection($suits));
```

Reservation table:
id - start_date - end_date

There are reservations from 18 September to 28 September. I do not want any dates if a user selects 20 September from 14 September.
I have tried the `whereHas` function with Laravel, but I don't have any idea what the problem is.

Comment: I think you should validate those dates and return an error in that case.

Comment: it has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361628/how-to-query-between-two-dates-using-laravel-and-eloquent?rq=2

Comment: @Basta I tried but it didn't work. My user gives me both login and logout dates. There are both entry and exit dates in the database. I have 2 dates each and I need to compare them.

Comment: FYI At the beginning of your code for example you call `$endDate->addDay()->format('Y-m-d');` without assigning the resulting value back to a variable. Is that an accident? Maybe those columns are timestamps instead of datetime values, have you checked?